# Generate mock XML file from C# class hierachy

Tags: c#, xml, testing, reflection

In order to generate UBL-order documents in XML, I have created 44 classes in C# using Xml.Serialization. The class consist of a root class "OrderType" which contains a lot of properties (classes), which again contains more properties.

In order to test that the classes always will build a XML document that will pass a validation. I want a XML file containing all the possible nodes (at least once) the hierarchy of Classes/Properties can build.

A very reduced code example:

```
[XmlRootAttribute]
[XmlTypeAttribute]
public class OrderType
{
     public DeliveryType Delivery { get; set; }
     //+ 50 more properties
     public OrderType(){}
}

[XmlTypeAttribute]
public class DeliveryType 
{
     public QuantityType Quantity { get; set; }
     //+ 10 more properties
     public DeliveryType (){}
}
```

I have already tried to initialise some properties in some of the constructors and it works fine, but this method would take a whole week to finish.

So! Is there a smart an quick method to generate a Mock XML document with all properties initialized?

It's ok that the outer nodes just are defined e.g.:
     < Code />

Comment: Create a constructor in each class that sets each property to a default value.  It is good software design proactive to initialize each property.

Comment: @jdweng - as I wrote, I have already done that for a couple of the constructors, but to do it with all, it will take my a weeks work and I asked for another approach.

Comment: The only way is through a constructor or an xml file containing initial values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sometimes you have to do it on your own:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Reflection;
namespace extanfjTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OrderType ouo = new OrderType(DateTime.Now);
            SetProperty(ouo);
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderType));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:/Projects/group.xml", FileMode.Create);
            ser.Serialize(fs, ouo);
            fs.Close();
        }

        public static void SetProperty(object _object)
        {
            if (_object == null)
            { return; }
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in _object.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if ("SemlerServices.OIOUBL.dll" != prop.PropertyType.Module.Name)
                { continue; }
                if (prop.PropertyType.IsArray)
                {
                    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType.GetElementType());
                    Array _array = Array.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType.GetElementType(), 1);
                    _array.SetValue(instance, 0);
                    prop.SetValue(_object, _array, null);
                    SetProperty(instance);
                }
                else
                {
                    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);
                    prop.SetValue(_object, instance, null);
                    SetProperty(instance);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```